# My program is supposed to list player's scores under their team names but prints the wrong ones. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, struct

I'm writing a program to log baseball teams, players, and averages. It's supposed to read in team names, how many teams there are, how many players their are, and then take player names + his team + his average. After, it should print the teams initially entered when only teams were prompted, and each of the players from it and their averages. However, it does the last part wrong. My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Player {
    char name[50];
    char teamName[50];
    float battingAv;
};

int main(void)
{
    int userNumber;
    printf("Enter the number of teams you wish to record: ");
    scanf("%d", &userNumber);
    int i;
    char teams[userNumber][40];
    for (i = 0; i < userNumber; i++) {
        char name[40];
        printf("Enter the name(s) of the teams: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        strcpy(teams[i], name);
    }

    int q;
    for (q = 0; q < userNumber; q++) {
        printf("Team %d is %s\n", q + 1, teams[q]);
    }

    int numOfPlayers;
    printf("Enter the TOTAL number of players for all teams: ");
    scanf("%d", &numOfPlayers);
    int j;
    struct Player playersEntered[numOfPlayers];
    for (j = 0; j < numOfPlayers; j++) {

        printf("Enter the %d Player name, Team name, and batting average: ", j + 1);
        scanf("%s %s %f", &playersEntered[j].name, &playersEntered[j].teamName, &playersEntered[j].battingAv);
    }

    printf("Listing of players and batting average according to team names:: \n");
    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < userNumber; m++) {
        int n;
        printf("%s-\n", teams[m]);
        for (n = 0; n < numOfPlayers; n++) {
            //if(playersEntered[n].teamName == teams[m])
            int result = strcmp(playersEntered[n].teamName, teams[m]);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                printf("\t%s %f\n ", playersEntered[m].name, playersEntered[m].battingAv);
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My logic is that the last loop should go thru playersEntered, and compare the team name given for that particular player to the list of teams entered at the start, so it would only print their name under the team they're listed for. But my output is getting it wrong.

My output should be like this:[image]

Comment: _Side note:_ I found the problems as did Swordfish, so I won't post an answer. But, if you compile with `-Wall`, several other lines get flagged. For example, `scanf("%s", &name);` It should be `scanf("%s", name);` This is similar to Swordfish's admonishment about the `strcpy`. Such warnings should be corrected as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> printf("\t%s %f\n ", playersEntered[m].name, playersEntered[m].battingAv);
> ```

-->

```
printf("\t%s %f\n ", playersEntered[n].name, playersEntered[n].battingAv);
```

Such mistakes are best prevented by not using `m` and `n` (or `i` and `l` or `j`) for nested loop variables.

---

btw:

> ```
> strcpy(teams[i], &name);
> ```

You don't need the address-of operator for `name`. The name of an array is automagically the address of its first element.

---

Pattern seen several times:

> ```
> int m;
> for(m = 0; m < userNumber; m++) {
> ```

Please, just define the variable within the `for`-statement:

```
for(int m = 0; m < userNumber; ++m) { // ...
```

---

You are using `int` for indexes into objects in memory. The correct type would be `size_t` (`<stddef.h>`) which is guaranteed to be big enough to hold all possible object sizes and indexes. The `scanf()`-format for it is `"%zu"`.

---

Talking bout `scanf()`:

Never! Realy NEVER! Use `"%s"` without specifying a WIDTH (=maximum characters to read) which is one less than there is space in the parameter given to `scanf()`:

```
char name[40];
scanf("%39s", name);
```